# Using Binary Search to find the sub array with the largest sum modulo x, my solution uses iterative search.

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, binary-search

I'm working on a hackerrank.com problem. The basic premise is given an array `A`, and a modulo `m`, find the subarray `B` that renders the largest value `sum(B)%m`. So the sub array that gives the largest sub array which sum mod `m` is the largest.

My basic approach is iteratively address every sub array, and keep track of the largest sum.

I have two questions:

1. How could I solve this with binary search? I don't understand how to apply the binary search concept here.
2. What is wrong with my current code.

Thanks for your help.

```
# https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximise-sum

# Accept input
##

def respond_bad_input
    puts "Bad input."
end

def check_for_new_max(mod, array, old_max)
    (get_mod_sum(mod,array)) > old_max
end

def get_mod_sum(mod, array)
    (array.inject{ |sum,x| sum + x }) % mod
end

index_size = 0
index_modulo = 1
index_array = 2

test_cases_count = 0
test_cases = []

input_array = ARGF.to_a

if input_array.count > 0
    test_cases_count = input_array[0]
else
    respond_bad_input
end 

(1..(input_array.count-1)).step(2).each do |index|
    if input_array.count-1 > index+1
        respond_bad_input
    else
        size = input_array[index].split(" ")[0].to_i
        modulo = input_array[index].split(" ")[1].to_i
        test_array = input_array[index+1].split(" ")
        test_array.map!{ |value| value.to_i }

        test_cases.push([size, modulo, test_array ])
    end
end

# Run each test case
##
test_cases.each do |current_case|
    max_value = 0

    current_case[index_array].each_with_index do |value, index|

        sub_array = [value]

        if check_for_new_max(current_case[index_modulo], sub_array, max_value)
            max_value = get_mod_sum(current_case[index_modulo], sub_array)
        end

        (index..(current_case[index_array].count-1)).each do |sub_index|
            sub_array = sub_array.push sub_index

            if check_for_new_max(current_case[index_modulo], sub_array, max_value)
                max_value = get_mod_sum(current_case[index_modulo], sub_array)
                max_array = sub_array
            end             
        end
    end

    puts max_value
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, construct a prefix (mod) sum array, S, such that:

```
S[i] = sum(A[0..i]) % m
```

This can easily be done in one linear scan using the relationship:

```
S[0] = A[0] % m
S[i] = (S[i-1] + A[i]) % m
```

As you construct this prefix sum array, however, you also want to find out "what is the maximum mod-sum I can make that ends with `A[i]`? You already know `sum(A[0..i]) % m`, which is `S[i]`.

Arbitrarily, what is `sum(A[a..i]) % m` for `a > 0`? It is simply:

```
(S[i] - S[a-1]) % m
```

If you choose `a` such that `S[a-1] <= S[i]`, you'll end up with a mod-sum between `a` and `i` that is *less than* (at best, equal to) the mod-sum between `0` and `i`.

So you'll have to pick `a` such that `S[a-1] > S[i]`. If such element exists, `S[i] - S[a-1]` will be negative. But `(-x) % m == m - x` for `x <= m`. So, we want to end up with `x` that is closest to `0` as possible.

In other words, find the *smallest* `S[a-1]`, for `0 < a < i`, such that `S[a-1] > S[i]`.

If, as you compute and store your `S[i]` elements in the prefix (mod) sum array, you maintain a tree of previous prefix sum values, you can perform the search for "maximum mod-sum ending at element `i`" in O(lg n) using binary search methods.

As you do this, greedily select the maximum mod-sum value you see.

The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
input: A, m

S := initialize a prefix array of the same size as array A
S[0] := A[0] % m
max_mod_sum := S[0]
T := initialize an empty self-balancing binary search tree
for i in [1, N):
    S[i] = (S[i-1] + A[i]) % m
    max_ending_at_i := S[i]
    # finds the "next", aka smallest, number bigger than the argument
    prev_sum := find_next(T, S[i])
    if prev_sum is found:
        max_ending_at_i := (S[i] - prev_sum) % m
    max_mod_sum = max(max_mod_sum, max_ending_at_i)
    insert(T, S[i])
return max_mod_sum
```

The runtime should be in O(n lg n) with O(n) space for the prefix sum array and tree.